# Blocked to initramfs unable to enter the system?

Tags: linux

I entered the live environment and installed Grub on my hard drive, placing the 6.4.0 kernel in the `/dev/sda3` location, through `mkinitramfs -o /mnt/boot/initrd` created the `initrd` and placed it in the `/dev/sda3` location, but it got stuck here during startup, as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

But when I enter the live environment, I can see`/dev/sda3`, as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

What's going on? I followed this link([mdadm: no devices listed in conf file were found - Debian 8 with GPT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265884/mdadm-no-devices-listed-in-conf-file-were-found-debian-8-with-gpt)) and set rootdelay in grub.cfg and executed update grub, which is still the same. Additionally, after entering initramfs, the keyboard was unable to input, so I don't know what happened

grub.cfg:

```
#Begin cfg
set default=0
set timeout=4

set root=(hd0,gpt3)

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Test-6.4.0-rt" {
    linux /bzImage rw root=/dev/sda3 rootdelay=90
    initrd /initrd
}
```

fstab:

```
#device mount-point type options dump fsck order
/dev/sda3   /         ext4  defaults   0 1
/dev/sda2   /boot     ext4  defaults   0 1
/dev/sda1   /boot/efi vfat  umask=0077 0 0
proc   /proc proc  defaults 0 0
sysfs  /sys  sysfs defaults 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
tmpfs /var  tmpfs defaults 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs  default  0  0
devpts  /dev/pts  devpts defaults  0  0
#none   /tmp  ramfs defaults 0 0
#mdev   /dev  ramfs defaults 0 0
```

reply **telcoM** and **Tom Yan**， drivers exist:

```
sudo unmkinitramfs initrd .
ls main/lib/modules/6.1.0-10-amd64/kernel/drivers/ata/ahci.ko
ls main/lib/modules/6.1.0-10-amd64/kernel/drivers/scsi/sd_mod.ko
```

====================Problem recurrence=============================

update 6.4.0-rt8:

```
$ ls main/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/scsi/sd_mod.ko
main/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/scsi/sd_mod.ko
$ ls main/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/ata/ahci.ko
main/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/kernel/drivers/ata/ahci.ko
```

#1
[image]
#2
[image]

Comment: Normally you need generate initramfs after chrooting into the corresponding installation so that it can determine correctly which driver modules are required to mount root. You can also see if your distro provide a way for you to generate a "fallback" initramfs though, which should include most if not all potential drivers.

Comment: The thing is, if you generate without chroot, the initramfs would include module files from the current installation/environment, which may not be loadable if the target installation has a different kernel build.

Comment: @TomYan Can you help me check again? This problem has reappeared, but I have checked my driver and they are all available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the drivers needed to access your `/dev/sda` disk is neither built into the kernel nor available as loadable modules within initramfs.

If this is a typical desktop or laptop system, the missing driver would probably be the `ahci` kernel module or its dependencies: `libahci`, `libata` and `sd-mod`. If these modules are not available, neither the `/dev/sda` whole-disk device node nor the device nodes for any partition devices (e.g. `/dev/sda3`) will not appear.

If `/dev/sda` exists but the partition device nodes don't, then the kernel is missing the appropriate partition table support.

If the device nodes are available but mounting it fails, a typical cause for that would be a missing filesystem driver module.

Comment: Let's not forget sd-mod and the filesystem driver.

Comment: @TomYan Good point, edited.

Comment: @yanzhang92 See my second comment under your post

Comment: @TomYan Sorry, I just saw it, so what do you mean is that I should not generate initrd in other environments, but rather execute mkinitramfs - o to generate initrd in chroot?

Comment: You said you are using a 6.4.0 kernel, but those driver modules are for kernel version 6.1.0. The modules for an older kernel version won't necessarily work with a newer one, and they definitely won't work if the kernel build process is configured to sign the kernel modules & require valid signatures for Secure Boot compatibility.

Comment: @yanzhang92 yes a chroot of the target installation (which has the 6.4 kernel installed).

Comment: @telcoM Yes, I just noticed this issue because my computer and live environment are both Debian12, and the kernel is 6.1. The initrd created using mkinitramfs - o on Debian12 is 6.1.0, but the kernel I compiled is 6.4.0.

Comment: `mkinitramfs` is a low-level tool. On Debian, there should be a more user-friendly `update-initramfs`. If you have already installed the 6.4.0 kernel's modules to  the appropriate subdirectory of `/lib/modules` (i.e. with `make modules_install`), then you should be able to automatically create a suitable initramfs with e.g. `update-initramfs -c -k <kernel version string>`. Just replace the `<kernel version string>` with the appropriate  `/lib/modules/` subdirectory name that matches your 6.4.0 kernel.

Comment: @telcoM When I updated the kernel to 6.4.0 and executed `update-initramfs -c -k 6.4.0-rt8`, I found that the generated initrd was very large, with 470M, to the point where after restarting, it displayed: `error: out of memory`.

Comment: @telcoM Can you help me check again? This problem has reappeared, but I have checked my driver and they are all available.

Comment: In the `(initramfs)` prompt, do a `lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules` to see which modules have been successfully loaded. Also check `dmesg` to see if there are any error messages.